# Подтверждение пароля в Angular

Tags: angularjs, input, валидация, auth

Есть форма регистрации с двумя полями: пароль и подтверждение пароля. Если нажать кнопку с незаполненными полями, появится tooltip и красная обводка. Кроме того, даже после расфокусирования формы при `input:hover` появляется подсказка с текстом ошибки. Как сделать чтобы **в точности такой же** эффект появлялся когда пароли не совпадают?

```js
(function() {
var validationApp = angular.module("validationApp", [])
validationApp.controller("ValidationCtrl", function() {
  
})

})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="validationApp">
  <form ng-controller="ValidationCtrl">
    <input type="password" ng-model="password" required='' />
    <input type="password" ng-model="repeat-password" required='' />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/oceinic/pen/GoZwJR)

Comment: Под "стандартной" стилизацией понимается HTML5 сообщения о валидации? [пример в Chrome](http://i.imgur.com/kZMskno.jpg)

Comment: @MichaelRadionov не только. Ещё input[title] добавляется при hover. Может быть что-то ещё, чего я не заметил

Comment: Пытаться стилизовать под "родные" UI элементы браузера бесполезная затея - в каждом браузере и операционной системе (учитывайте также и мобильные браузеры) они рисуются по-своему и в любой момент их внешний вид может поменяться. Лучше опираться на свои стили, которые везде будут выглядеть одинаково, а HTML5 валидацию просто отключить, если мешает.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov, погуглил и нашел метод element.setCustomValidity(). Разве он не подойдёт?

Comment: Интересно, не знал об этом, спасибо. Но видимо это мало где поддерживается на данный момент.

Comment: вот из за таких проблем я и не люблю angular, ember, ... etc. Простая задача может отнять кучу времени. Как можно оценивать время и стоимость работ если так просто упороться? P.S Работал с Ember + Rails

Comment: @Invision, я потратил несколько минут, чтобы написать ответ. На основании чего сделан вывод, что эта задача должна отнять кучу времени? Если человек впервые видит ангуляр, то, вероятно, да, но в таком случае это утверждение применимо к абсолютно любой технологии.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
angular.module("validationApp", [])

.controller("ValidationCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function (event) {
    console.log($scope.password);
    event.preventDefault();
  };
})

.directive('mySameAs', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$validators.sameAs = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
        return modelValue === scope.$eval(attrs.mySameAs);
      };
      
      scope.$on('destroy', scope.$watch(attrs.mySameAs, function () {
        ngModel.$validate();
      }));
    }
  };
})
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
  border-color: red;
}

.ng-dirty.ng-invalid-same-as {
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}

.error-msg {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

.ng-dirty.ng-invalid-same-as ~ .error-msg.invalid-same-as {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="validationApp" novalidate>
  <form ng-controller="ValidationCtrl" ng-submit="submit($event)">
    <input type="password" ng-model="password" required />
    <input type="password" ng-model="repeatPassword" required my-same-as="password" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <span class="error-msg invalid-same-as">Passwords do not match</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: я думаю стоило бы подробнее написать про директиву, ngModelController и как это все вместе работает :-)

Comment: Ответ неполный. Нужно чтобы появлялось текстовое сообщение об ошибке

Comment: @Oceinic, а в чём именно проблема показать сообщение?

Comment: @Oceinic, ответ обновлён.

Comment: @Qwertiy, дополнил вопрос

Comment: @Oceinic, задай отдельный вопрос про стилизацию.

Comment: @Qwertiy, подумал над этим. Потом при сабмите будет удобнее написать formName.$valid и получить false, так как мы записали в ng-model дополнительный валидатор. В этом случае код самого сабмита станет проще. Но! Если у нас какая то сложная валидация на поле, лучше делать функцию  в контроллере и использовать ее везде. И на полях как ng-model и при сабмите как валидацию

Comment: @flybox, если в `ng-model` провалена валидация, то в контроллере будет видимо значение `undefined`, независимо от того, что введено в поле. А ещё я не вижу ни одной причины дублировать валидацию в контроллере.

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь ng-class для установки ng-invalid при срабатывании условия не равенства паролей. В проверку так же желательно включить условие, что пароль не пуст, иначе они будут светиться по умолчанию.

```
<input type="password" model="password" required='' ng-class="(password!='' && password!=repeatPassword) ? 'ng-invalid' : ''" />
<input type="password" model="repeatPassword" required='' ng-class="(password!='' && password!=repeatPassword) ? 'ng-invalid' : ''" />
```

Comment: Слишком низкоуровневый код. Такую функциональность обычно извлекают в контроллер

Comment: @Oceinic, в директиву же.

Comment: Этот ответ намного понятнее и нагляднее. Вы работаете с view в данный момент, а не с отправкой формы на сервер. В этом случае и используется ng-class. Если есть проблемы с отображением в первую очередь все смотрят во view, а первым вариантом код запутывается только. Единственное что надо все что в ng-class вынести в функцию в контроллер. И будет намного лаконичнее, понятнее.

Comment: @flybox, форма должна иметь нормальную валидацию. А этот костыль добавляет раскраску, но ангуляр считает форму валидной. Это плохой способ.

Comment: @Qwertiy, отвечу как комментарий к вашему ответу.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь плагином validation-match

https://github.com/TheSharpieOne/angular-validation-match

Comment: По сравнению с моим кодом, там как минимум потенциальная утечка watch'ей и использование недокументированного приватного метода.